# place an image in the middle of the page if it is the only image?

Tags: floats

I apologize if this is a basic question: I have to include a fairly large diagram that takes up at least half or more of a page and would not mind if that is the only thing on the page (it is a tikzpicture which I am `\input`-ing from another file within a `figure` environment).
I have a constraint though which is that the picture **must** appear right after the heading.

I have experimented with all the `figure` options like `H` (from package `float`), `!h`, `t`, `p`, etc. For example:

```
\section{Flowchart} % diagram must be beneath this heading
\begin{figure}[H]
   \input{flowchart.tex}
   \caption{foo}
\end{figure}
```

If the picture *is* going to be taking up the whole page without allowing any other text on the same page, I would like it to be placed at the middle of the page instead of at the top. Removing options `[]` altogether places the image exactly where I want but the heading gets pushed to the next page.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you are using `[H]` to suppress the behaviour that you are asking for, Just delete that or if necessary use `[p]` but just deleting `[H]` is probably enough

Comment: or dependimg what you mean by `only thing on the page` put `\clearpage` before the `\section` or after the figure or between the heading and the figure (or all of those places)

Comment: Try putting a `\FloatBarrier` from the `placeins` package, or use the `section` package option, next to the section heading, this will stop floats from below from appearing above it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

may be this will work for you

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\section{Flowchart} % diagram must be beneath this heading
\vfill
\begin{center}
   \input{flowchart.tex}
   \captionof{figure}{foo}
\end{center}
\vfill
\newpage
a new page starts here
\end{document}
```